# What permission is needed to use S3 listObjectVersions in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I currently have a lambda that uses the node sdk call [listObjectVersions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectVersions-property) to list all the versions of a specific file. However, I can't figure out what permission in my policy will grant the lambda permission to make this call. I've searched the AWS documentation and I can not find any information.

Here are the current permissions in my policy:

```
- PolicyName: S3Policy
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - s3:PutObject
          - s3:PutObjectAcl
          - s3:GetObject
          - s3:GetObjectVersion
          - s3:ListObjectVersions
          - s3:DeleteObject
          - s3:ListBucket
```

When I execute the lambda I get an `Access Denied` when making the call. I've changed my policy to allow the action `s3:*` and the lambda works. However, I do not want to grant full access to s3.

What Action do I need to add to allow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon S3 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html):

> **ListBucketVersions:** Use the versions subresource to list metadata about all of the versions of objects in a bucket.

I tested this as follows:

- Created an IAM User
- Assigned the policy below
- Ran the command: `aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket my-bucket`

It worked successfully.

The policy was:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucketVersions",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, while the naming seems a bit strange (List **Object** Versions vs List **Bucket** Versions), it is the correct permission to use.

Answer (score 9):

You need to update your `Resource` in the policy.

`s3:ListBucketVersions` is the action that you're looking for.

It should be as follows:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucketVersions",
            "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Try to change your policy accordingly.

Comment: I should have clarified my I removed my actual resource bucket. This is not the issue

Comment: Then in `Resource`, use wildcard, "*", so it can be used for any S3 bucket whether already existing or created later.

Comment: That's not the issue though. The issue is I can not use the command `listObjectVersions` due to not having the correct action. The resources listed on my bucket are fine, I removed them from my question for clarity. When I change the policy to accept actions `s3:*` it works. Meaning, there is an action to allow `listObjectVersions` to be executed but I don't know what that action is.

Comment: That is `s3:GetObjectVersion`. Following are all the actions related to versioning.
"s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
"s3:ListBucketVersions",
"s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
"s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
"s3:GetBucketVersioning",
"s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
"s3:GetObjectVersion". I have updated my answer.

Comment: You can also use AWS Managed, `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` policy as well.