# S3 unable to run list-object-versions on a bucket with tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a s3 bucket with versioning enabled. Calling `aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket my-bucket` fails with the following error:
`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectVersions operation: Access Denied`

The IAM user account has `AmazonS3FullAccess` so it should have all the needed permissions already on that side. The IAM user is also not the owner of the bucket and is from a completely separate account.

[The docs state](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/list-object-versions.html) I only need the `s3:ListBucketVersions` permission which I have enabled below so I'm not sure what else is missing.

The following permissions are set for an external :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Test_list",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<user arn>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Test_get",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<user arn>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket/*",
        {
            "Sid": "Test_get-bucket-location",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<user arn>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57732033/what-permission-is-needed-to-use-s3-listobjectversions-in-aws

Comment: @jarmod I have `s3:ListBucketVersions` set already

Comment: When granting S3 permissions to specific users, it is better to grant the permissions via a policy on the **IAM User** rather than doing it via a **Bucket Policy**. You say that the user has `AmazonS3FullAccess`, so there is no need to also grant access via a Bucket Policy. It would appear that the AWS CLI command you are using is _not_ using the credentials that you think it is using. Please run `aws sts get-caller-identity` to discover which user credentials are being used.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That is true but I should have mentioned above the IAM User is NOT the owner of the bucket so I don't think that applies. I only want these specific permissions for the IAM User on the bucket.

Comment: Ah! I see you have updated your question to mention that the Bucket is in a different account to the IAM User -- that is an important piece of information. So, are you saying that the IAM User has `AmazonS3FullAccess` and the Bucket Policy you have shown is attached to the S3 bucket (which is in a different account)? In that case, what you have shown should work correctly. To debug the permissions, you could _temporarily_ change the Bucket Policy to grant `s3:*` permissions to the IAM User, for both `sourcebucket` and `sourcebucket/*`. This will tell you whether the Bucket Policy is at fault.

Comment: I tried setting both permissions to `s3:*` and still get the same permission denied error

Comment: Now I'm not sure at all, I originally thought I had a mistake in the bucket policy, but I doubled checked and the IAM user does indeed have s3:* permissions on s3 as well

Comment: Are you able to do any other operations on the bucket, such as `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name`?

Comment: `ls` and `cp` to local and to another bucket all work

Comment: It looks like requester pays being enabled is causing the issue, if i disable that it works, strange since there's no option to add that for the list-object-versions api.

Comment: Found this github issue as well https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/7952